# $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to3i}\frac{-3z}{z^2-9-6iz}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Is the following limit $\infty$ or does it not exist?
I'm asking this question to hopefully dispel a confusion I'm having ([Limit of $f(z)=\frac 1z$ as $z$ approaches $0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/333386/21813)).

$$\displaystyle\lim_{z\to3i}\frac{-3z}{z^2-9-6iz}$$

Comment: limit $\infty$ is equivalent to does not exist, at least in your case.

Comment: You can interpret $\lim f=\infty$ to mean $\lim(1/f)=0$.

Comment: @gerry Well, I'm a little confused because I notice that for the given function, as I plug in various values of z near 3i, I'm getting wildly different values for the function. Intuitively, I feel that the function doesn't even approach infinity, but perhaps I'm still thinking in terms of real analysis? I'm not quite certain what limit = $\infty$ means exactly, in complex analysis.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Forget my last comment, sorry. I now see what this notation means. Infinite is unsigned here. I've never used this notation, I'll need to get used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responding to your comment on the question, which seems to be the real question, this is the same as $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac 1z$ in the complex plane.  If you look at values near zero you will find wildly different values, but the magnitude is always large.  The wildly different values come from the argument.  As you get closer to zero, the magnitude approaches infinity.  It is like (this supports calling it the Riemann sphere) the fact that longitude is undefined at the north and south poles.  Let one be $r=0$ and the other be $r=\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. But don't both (north and south) poles correspond to $r=\infty$?

Comment: @Ryan:  one corresponds to $r=0$, the other to $r=\infty$  Adding the point at infinity closes up the plane into a sphere.

Comment: Oh, I finally sorted out my visualisation of the sphere. Cheers!