# What is $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{z}$ in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the limit $$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{z}$$

that I want to find for $z \in \mathbb{C}$. If for $z = x+iy$ with $x = \operatorname{Re}{z}$ and $y = \operatorname{Im}{z}$, I restrict $z$ to the positive real axis $z = x$, I obtain the limit $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} = \pm \infty.$$ Since the limit approaches different values, the limit does not exist. Is this correct? This thread
[Limit of $f(z)=\frac 1z$ as $z$ approaches $0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333386/limit-of-fz-frac-1z-as-z-approaches-0/333403) mentions the limit to be $\infty_{\mathbb{C}}$ so I am confused.

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted, it seems like a perfectly reasonable question. I've edited the title to include latex.

Comment: @preferred_anon Thanks. I didn't know you can include LaTeX in titles!

Comment: To properly answer this question would take a lot of effort, so here is a brief comment instead. The notation $f(x) \to \pm \infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is a shorthand notation to mean "$f$ is unbounded in the positive/negative direction" respectively. It is not a real limit, and it does not respect usual limit properties. The function $f(x) = 1/x$ does not have a limit as $x \to 0$ in either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, in both cases because it is unbounded near $0$. But as a function from the Riemann sphere to itself, $f(0) = \infty$ and the corresponding limit is well-defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In $\mathbb{C}$, there is no distinction between $\infty$ and $- \infty$. This is because, in $\mathbb{C}$, one can approach $\infty$ in any direction. Therefore, use the convention that

$$\lim_{z \to a} f(z) = \infty \iff \lim_{z \to a} |f(z)| = \infty,$$

where the last limit is a real limit and is defined in the real sense. The concept of a point at infinity in $\mathbb{C}$ has a very elegant interpretation through Stereographic projection and the Riemann-sphere. To put it very shortly, we can define what is sometimes called *the extended complex plane* $\mathbb{C}_{\infty} = \mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$, which is isometric to the Riemann-sphere (read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere). Topoligists will sometimes refer to $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ as the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{C}$, meaning that it is a compact metric space differing from $\mathbb{C}$ by just one point.

Edit: Now to the limit in question. You have already observed that the limit does not exist in the sense that it does not approach a complex number. With that in mind, try to evaluate the limit using the equivalence above. We consider

$$\lim_{z \to 0} \left| \frac{1}{z} \right| = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{|z|} =  \lim_{r \to 0^+} \frac{1}{r}=\infty.$$

Comment: Thanks, I already understand the intuition behind the complex infinity. In terms of this question, even if I look at the limit in terms of polar form $z=re^{i\theta}$, I'm still getting that the limit does not exist.

Comment: You need to apply the equivalence above. See edit for calculation.

Comment: Thanks, I was being an idiot.

Comment: Nono, this is a subtle question that I would quess most professors don't address. As, preferred_anon pointed out, a perfectly reasonable question. Glad I could help!